# Objective-c : initialize instance var

Tags: objective-c

I am new to objective-c. My object reportingTime is nil in init method. What I am doing wrong ? How can I initialize reportingTime and set firstweekday ?

I have the following interface and implementation

My interface file Calculation.h

```
@interface Calculate : NSObject {

NSCalendar *reportingTime;
....
....
}
@property NSCalendar *reportingTime;

@end
```

And my implementation file Calculate.m

```
#import "Calculate.h"

@implementation Calculate

@synthesize reportingTime;

- (id)init
{
    if(self = [super init]) {
        reportingTime = [[NSCalendar alloc] init];
        [reportingTime setFirstWeekday:1];

        // reportingTime is nil ??????
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
- (id)initWithCalendarIdentifier:(NSString *)string
```

instead of standart init method.
See more: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html

Comment: And why is #import "Calculate.m" in Calculate.m?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
reportingTime = [[NSCalendar alloc] init];
```

use:

```
reportingTime = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] retain];
```

The retain because this is a direct assignment to the @property ivar and `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]` is a convenience method that returns an autoreleased var. If you are using ARC the retain is not necessary.

Comment: it was a typo it is Calculate I have changed it but still not working